# Adding a search bar into main menu on Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm making a website using Twitter's Bootstrap and everything is almost set but I can't  figure how to position a search bar into the main menu

Here is the website online
http://testings.coffeecup.com/index1.html

Each time I put it anywhere on the container it screws up either.

EDIT:

I managed to add it:

http://gyazo.com/e76b7cfa8e25b9ef2913d588b28ea894

But I still can't position it on the right.

The css I'm using

```
      .navbar-search {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-search .search-query {
    float:right;
}

.navbar-search .icon-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    background-image: url("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the `<div class="navbar-inner">` include the search bar `<input>` with whichever attributes you need .. after just float it to the right and adjust the margins so its centered vertically in the nav-bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the search-bar inside `<div class="navbar-inner">` and after `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">`.

The code for the search bar:

```
<input id="search" class="span3" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **pull-right** class

i used it in the container

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                  <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="">
                      <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
              </div>
```

REsult :
[image]